# Change the location of saved screenshot when screenshot taken by printscreen button in GNOME 3

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, gnome-screenshot, print-screen

I want to change the default location of "*Save a screenshot to Pictures*" to save it to Desktop.

If that is not possible, is there any other way to do it? I am using Ubuntu GNOME 17.04.

**NOTE:** I don't want to change the location with `dconf-editor` as it changes the location of screenshot applet and not of the shortcut I require.
[image]