# changing PrintScreen screenshot directory in Lubuntu

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, home-directory, dconf, print-screen

I'm using the most recent version of Lubuntu based on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

I read this October 2017 discussion on the topic [Change the location of saved screenshot when screenshot taken by printscreen button](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961094/change-the-location-of-saved-screenshot-when-screenshot-taken-by-printscreen-but/961149#961149) so in trying to emulate Pomsky's answer, I installed dconfEditor (I assume this comes with standard Ubuntu, I had to install it via Synaptic Package Manager since I don't think it came with Lubuntu) however I reached a snag.

I navigated to org / gnome but there was no gnome-screenshot there to open to find auto-save-directory. Does anyone know how to find this in Lubuntu? I figure the directory must be set up differently.

I had also tried this command in the Terminal:

- gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory 'file:///home/USERNAME/DESIREDFOLDER'

But it returned this error:

- No such schema “org.gnome.gnome-screenshot”

The way it works now is if I press PrintScreen it generates an image inside the Home/USERNAME directory. I'd like to dedicate a folder specifically to it though, so that I don't get mixed up and risk moving/deleting important Home folders while moving/deleting these screenshots. I made such a folder but have not been able to get the pictures to appear there.

<strike>I can start a separate question for it, but if anyone knows how I can emulate left mouse clicks and right mouse clicks w/ keyboard keys (like mousekeys, preferably using number pad's 5 like I was used to) that would be great. My right button in particular is stuck and doesn't work and the key to the left of the rightmost CTRL doesn't always work the same way.</strike>

Comment: Please avoid clubbing issues in one question!

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu 18.04 uses `scrot`, not `gnome-screenshot`, as its default.

If you haven't added `gnome-screenshot` yourself, `apt policy scrot` and `apt policy gnome-screenshot` will make things clear.

Use something like:

`scrot -u /path/to/desired/folder/"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)".png` for an immediate screenshot of the active window

or

`scrot -d10 /path/to/desired/folder/"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)".png` for a screenshot with a delay of `10s` of the fullscreen; this option is useful for capturing drop-down menus

or

`scrot -s  /path/to/desired/folder/"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)".png` for selecting an area of the screen to be captured.

`$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)".png` is the filename I use to "timestamp" the screenshots and to save in `.png` format.

Read `man scrot` for more on `scrot` and `man date` for naming files with timestamps.

---

In case you want to use keyboard shortcuts to launch the commands given above ...

Open PcManFM, the default file manager in Lubuntu.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to enable viewing of hidden files and folders.

Open the `.config` folder and then, within that, the `openbox` folder.
In the `openbox` folder, you'll see `lubuntu-rc.xml`. Make a backup of this file somewhere convenient and rename it to `ORIGINAL-lubuntu-rc.xml`. This is important in case bad things happen.

Open the `lubuntu-rc.xml` file which is in `~/.config/openbox` using `Leafpad`. **Don't double-click on it. It will cause the file to open in a web browser which isn't what we want.**
Scroll down till you see the following content:

```
  <!--
      Take a screenshot of the current window with scrot when Alt+Print are pressed 
  -->
  <keybind key="Print">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>lxsession-default screenshot</command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
  <keybind key="A-Print">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>lxsession-default screenshot window</command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
```

**Very, very carefully,** replace that entire content with:

```
<keybind key="Print">        # Immediate scrot of active window
  <action name="Execute"><command>sh -c 'scrot -u /home/VistaRefugee/Pictures/"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)".png'</command></action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-Print">        # Delayed scrot of full screen
  <action name="Execute"><command>sh -c 'scrot -d10 /home/VistaRefugee/Pictures/"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)".png'</command></action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="S-Print">        # Interactive scrot
  <action name="Execute"><command>sh -c 'scrot -s /home/VistaRefugee/Pictures/"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)".png'</command></action>
</keybind>
```

Change `VistaRefugee/Pictures` to whatever you desire.

Save `lubuntu-rc.xml`.

Open `lxterminal` and run `openbox --reconfigure`. You should get back the terminal prompt. The purpose of `openbox --reconfigure` is to make the system aware of the changes you made. It also parses the content to ensure there aren't any syntax errors. If anything else happens, restore `lubuntu-rc.xml` from your back-up and give up or try again carefully.

Note that what goes into `lubuntu-rc.xml` is different than what you can run from a terminal because of how Openbox deals with certain characters.

- [can openbox's rc.xml and menu.xml take complex shell syntax?](https://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=27064)
- [List of XML and HTML character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Now, you can use

- <kbd>Print</kbd> to capture the entire screen.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> to capture a selected area of the screen
- <kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> to capture the entire screen after a delay of `10s`. Note that `W` is shorthand in `openbox` lingo for the `Super` key.

---

If you're planning to stay with Lubuntu 18.04 for a while, you may want to know more about Openbox, keeping in mind that `lubuntu-rc.xml` is just Lubuntu's name for what is also known as `lxde-rc.xml` or `rc.xml` in systems other than Lubuntu or where Openbox isn't used in the LXDE environment:

- [Documentation](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Contents)
- [LXDE: Meet The Heart & Soul — lxde-rc.xml](http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201011/page09.html)
- [Openbox - Edit rc.xml to Gain Control](http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201107/page08.html)

Comment: Can you explain why i should replace the default screenshot behavior with a full scrot command instead of configuring the lxsession defaults to invoke scrot correctly?  I mean, for me at least, it's *already* invoking scrot, although looking at my desktop.conf file I can't see how it assembles the command.