# How to configure "Print screen" button such that it directly ask for the place to save the screenshot in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, gnome-screenshot, print-screen

Till 16.04, when I press <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>, we used to get the "Save to" option which enabled us to save the screenshot into a desired folder. Now, with 18.04, pressing <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> saves the screenshot directly in the Pictures folder. I am unable to find a way to save the screenshot into the desired folder.

I have tried binding <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> with `gnome-screenshot -i`. However, this option currently requires me to go through two steps (press <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> and then again press "Take screenshot" button) instead of a single step (just <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>) to get the "Save to" dialogue box.

Any help is appreciated in this regard.

Comment: You probably can't achieve that (easily) with `gnome-screenshot`, that's [how it works in GNOME](https://askubuntu.com/a/118579/480481). So your best alternative is to use `gnome-screenshot -i` as you' already mentioned. Also you can [change the default save location](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961094/change-the-location-of-saved-screenshot-when-screenshot-taken-by-printscreen-but) from Pictures to some other directory if you want.

Comment: Please refer to this answer for an ugly workaround to replicate the old behaviour: https://askubuntu.com/a/1105345/480481

Comment: I really do not think my question is anywhere close to the question which you guys are pointing to.

Comment: @pomsky, as I said, I am referring to the similarity between the other person's question and my question. I am not at all referring to the validity of your answer to my question. His/her question is on how to select a specific area and save it to the clipboard or a folder (which can simply be achieved by binding a key with "gnome-screenshot -i"). His question is not at all pointed towards the steps involved in saving the screenshot. My question is specifically about converting the two step procedure to a single step. Hope you agree with me.

Comment: The other question is also essentially about *bringing back the old behaviour* as yours is. The asker just mentioned that they "*usually* take screenshot of an area" (emphasis mine) and hence they use <Shift>+<PrtScr> instead of just <PrtScr>. The core of the question is getting the dialogue as in the screenshot back like older Ubuntu releases just like yours. Just remember duplicates have a big role in the Stack Exchange network, they work as signposts and help organising the sites. Otherwise we would be having almost identical questions with almost identical answers clogging the sites.

Comment: If you disagree with the duplicate, please consider posting a new question at https://meta.askubuntu.com/ raising the issue to get a collective opinion from the Ask Ubuntu community.